# Shabbat Candle Lighting

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting

SHEMIRATH SHABBATH by Rav Yehoshua Y. Neuwirth ZT”L is, in my opinion, THE supreme, most authoritative English guide to the Halacha (and more!) of Shabbat and Yom Tov. I do have a question in understanding a section of it.

In Chapter 43—Kindling the Shabbath (sic) and Yom Tov Lights, General Laws, Rav Neuwirth writes:

43.38. a.

1. If the match goes out while one is in the process of kindling the lights, one must not reignite it from a Shabbath light which one has already kindled, even if one wishes to use the match for kindling another Shabbath light, but
2. the other Shabbath light may be kindled directly from the burning one.

How can one use an already-kindled light to light the remaining light or lights if he/she uses oil? If one uses oil, can a second match thus be used?

Many thanks for any help in interpreting this section of SHEMIRATH SHABBATH. Shabbat Shalom.

Answer (score 2):

The halacha in question is not about hilchos Shabbes, rather about ביזוי מצוות. Meaning, lighting a match (or anything else that will not stay lit lechvod shabbes) that has no kedusha  from a candle that has been lit lechvod shabbes and as such has a kedusha of a mitzva on it is considered ביזוי מצווה.
In other words, one can relight another match by striking the matchbox in order to light the other candles, all one is not allowed to do is to use the lechvod shabbes flame to relight said wick.

For further reference  see Mishna Berura 363:4 which is the source for this halacha in the  שש"כ.

Comment: Thanks very much, Yoreinu. I appreciate your time and insight.